# Configure mediaCodec dynamically

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

My question is very clear. Is it possible to configure media codec when codec is running.

Code sample:

```
codec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType( "video/avc" );
     MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(CodecConfigurations.MIME_TYPE,
            CodecConfigurations.WIDTH, CodecConfigurations.HEIGHT);
    Log.d( LOG_TAG, "Track Format: " + mime );
    format.setInteger( MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 125000 );
    format.setInteger( MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 15 );
    format.setInteger( MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar );
    format.setInteger( MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 5 );
    codec.configure( format, null, null, 0 );
    codec.start( );
```

Is it possible to reconfigure codec as below without stopping the codec?

```
format.setInteger( MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 10);
codec.configure( format, null, null, 0 );
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html)...

[image]

It would appear that you may only configure the codec from the uninitialized state, requiring you to stop/reset a running codec to do so.